# how do i associate my outlook with excel 2010

Tags: windows-8

I want to e-mail a doc from excel 2010, but it tells me I don't have a e-mail associated. it says to go to default program control panel. How do I set this up?

Comment: please elaborate...do you have outlook set up?

Answer (score 0):

Official Microsoft support site:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-office_install/cant-open-excel-attachments-from-outlook-except-by/b1f1d2a5-ca4e-4914-b107-5870131ad89d

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in default programs in your Control Panel and check that Outlook is the default e-mail client, then Excel will call it then.